# How Can i solve 'Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection(id:0)'?

Tags: react-native, tensor

How can I solve this error in react-native?

> 'Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection(id:0)'

Every time I use `const net = await facemesh.load()` this error occurs.

> [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'environment_1.env().platform.fetch')]

```
// TENSORFLOW DEPENDENCIES
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import * as facemesh from '@tensorflow-models/facemesh';
import { drawMesh } from './src/utilities';

   // LOAD FACemash
  const runFacemesh = async () => {
    const net = await facemesh.load();
      //{input:{width:640,height:480},scale:0.8});
  //   setInterval(()=>{
  //     detect(net);
  //   },100)
  };
  
  // //Detect function
  // const detect = async (net) => {
  //   if(typeof cameraRef.current !== "undefined" && cameraRef.current !== null){
  //     // get video properties
  //     const video = cameraRef.current.video;
  //     const videoWidth = cameraRef.current.video.videoWidth;
  //     const videoHeight = cameraRef.current.video.videoHeight;

  //     // set video width
  //     cameraRef.current.video.width = videoWidth;
  //     cameraRef.current.video.height = videoHeight;

  //     //set canvas width
  //     canvasRef.current.width = videoWidth;
  //     canvasRef.current.height = videoHeight;

  //     // make detection
  //     const face = await net.estimateFaces(video);
  //     console.log(face);

  //     //get canvas context from drawing
  //     const ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext("2d");
  //     drawMesh(face,ctx);
  //   }
  // }

  runFacemesh()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you add `.catch()` you will not have this issue. then you may check if net is error and decide should you go further or not.

```
 const net = await facemesh.load().catch((err) => err);
 if (net instanceof Error) {
   return;
 }
```

Comment: i used but it's not helping it's terminate code here and not executing the rest code.

Comment: if there is exception inside it will terminate the code. Just make console.log what is the exception. It is not ts error

Comment: *[TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'env().platform.fetch')].* this is error. How can i solve it?

Comment: I guess you need to import proper adapter `tfjs-react-native` in order to make navigator.platform proper work